# How to get facebook friends with using graph api v 2.2

Tags: java, android, facebook-graph-api

I am not able to get facebook friends using facebook graph api v 2.2.So anyone please tell me how to get facebook friend using graph api v 2.2. I want to get friends list using facebook id.

Comment: we should do a count on how often this question pops up on stackoverflow...

Comment: You should search before asking. It's recommended to post the things you have tried so far.

Comment: you might be right @LucianoRodríguez but now any search will render this link in the top 5 so reasons for downvoting would help

Answer (score 1):

Information with example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/friends

BUT:

> This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request.